# convert a text link to image link

Tags: javascript, image

I am in the middle of making a post system for my website, and i would like some javascript that would turn a text link like 
`<a href="path/to/image.jpg">Image</a>`
into
`<a href="path/to/image.jpg"><img src="path/to/image.jpg" /></a>`
but only turn it into an image link when something such as a regex recognises that the link is to an image.

Or i dont mind doing something like adding a data-type="image" attribute to the link, but i still need the code to turn it into an image link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alex solution is a better one, but if you could not add a class

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var a = $(this)
    if(a.text() == 'Image')
        a.html('<img src="'+a.href+'" >')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7AvJT/2/

Comment: You need jQuery in all the given answers. Look at the jsfiddles, it does work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif]"').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" />');
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/FcQzG/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend putting a class on all of the anchors links you want to convert. Let's say you choose to use a `convert` class. Then, you could use jQuery the add an `img` tag inside the anchor tag:

```
// for each anchor that needs converting
$('.convert').each(function() {
  // get the href of the anchor
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  // create the string we want to append to the anchor
  var imgString = '<img src="' + href + '" alt="" />';
  // and then append it
  $(this).append(imgString);
});
```